# No Sort/Group by Content Type?

Tags: office-365, content-type, view, sorting, grouping

When editing a View, there is no option to Sort or Group by Content Type. This could be very useful for making a folder-like experience, for finding files, or other use cases.

What design criteria led Microsoft to intentionally prevent Sort By / Group By functionality? (I know you can hack it in, but it shouldn't need a hack...)

This constraint suggests it is wrong for a site architecture to organize data by Content Type. How can someone group data by its type?

Comment: This question may have some degree of subjectivity, but it is not against the community guidelines. This question asks for information about specific SharePoint architecture decisions, and for work-arounds to a limitation to Views. It 'inspire[s] answers that explain “why” and “how”'.

Comment: The why and how isn't something known to us, there isn't any way to corroborate if it is true. So I might think it is because of reason x, you Bill might think it's because reason Y, and unless the asker has intimate knowledge of how and why SharePoint was developed the way it was, how can they award a proper answer? If you rephrase the question to ask  specifically how to hack in the fix, then that is answerable.

Answer (score 1):

How about Metadata Navigation for your App. It allows you to add content type as something that can be filtered on.

More info: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-C222A75D-8B18-44E2-9ED8-7EE4E0D23CFC